# How can I know when javascript all async operations ended?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm using WCF-Ajax enabled on my web site.

I need to save files asynchronically, but in the end I need to know when all the async operations finished.

```
function test()
{
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         saveFileService.SaveFile(arr[i], onSaveFileComplete);
   }

   //TODO: CHECK THAT **ALL** FILE SAVES ARE DONE  
}

function onSaveFileComplete(result)
{
  // ONE FILE SAVE ENDED SUCCESSFULLY
}
```

How to write the "TODO" part ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a global counter when you save the files...

```
var fiesCurrentlySaving = 0;

function test()
{
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         // Increase counter for the number of files saving
         filesCurrentlySaving++;

         // Save the file
         saveFileService.SaveFile(arr[i], onSaveFileComplete);
   }
}

function onSaveFileComplete(result)
{
    // Reduce the file counter
    filesCurrentlySaving--;

    if (filesCurrentlySaving <= 0)
    {
        // Do whatever you need to do now!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a counter variable and increment it in your completion callback. When it reaches `arr.length`, all the files will have been processed.

Something like:

```
function test()
{
    var processedFiles = 0, fileCount = arr.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < fileCount; i++) {
        saveFileService.SaveFile(arr[i], function() {
            // One file save ended successfully.
            if (++processedFiles == fileCount) {
                // All files have been processed.
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function test()
{
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 saveFileService.SaveFile(arr[i], onSaveFileComplete);
     if(i == arr.length)
     {
       //TODO: CHECK THAT **ALL** FILE SAVES ARE DONE 
     }   
}
}
```